# Find all the $p$-Sylow subgroups of $D_6$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, dihedral-groups

$|D_6|=12=2^23.$ I started with $3$. I know that the number of $3$-Sylow subgroups, denoted $n_3$, is: $1,4,7...$ and I also know that $n_3|2^2$. e.g, $n_3=1, 4$. How can I show that it can't be $4$? After all, Sylow subgroups are not disjoint. Suppose I showed it is $1$. How exactly do I find the $3$-sylow subgroup itself? I would really appreciate you help.

Answer (score 2):

Find a $3$ sylow subgroup, and check if it's normal. if it is - it's the only one. otherwise, there are 4 of them.

to find the $3$ sylow subgroup, just find a subgroup of three elements, giving the structure of $D_6$

Comment: So I'd have to check that with every element, right? 
A bit exhausting but if that's my only option then I will do it

Comment: first find the subgroup, then think about it. maybe you'll have a better way to check if it's a normal subgroup

Comment: I did find a subgroup but I don't know how to show that :( 
I tried to work with Conjugay but I am not quite sure...

Comment: @Meitar If you find it deductively, as in, finding conditions on $j$ s.t. $r^j$ has order 3, you'll find the conditions are unique anyways. This together with $(sr^j)^2 = 1 \ \forall j$ should allow you to conclude.

Comment: @Meitar Alternatively, what tzoorp suggests is using a known fact about the subgroup you'll find. It has to do with commutator subgroups I believe.